# React Native refresh data async call, array not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am refreshing data for my app, and passing a refreshing prop down.

How can I show nothing while refresh is `true` and the documents array is being rendered. Only showing 'No documents available', when refreshing is false and documents array has rendered?

```
const DocumentsListWidget = ({ refreshing }) => {

  const {
    documents: { documents },
    policy: {
      policyInfo: { PolicyId },
    },
  } = useSelector((state) => state);
  return (
    <SecureAreaWrapper
      ...
    >
      {documents.length > 0 ? (
        <FlatList
          scrollEnabled={false}
          data={documents}
          ListHeaderComponent={Header}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Item
              ...
            />
          )}
        />
      ) : (
        <Text style={documentsListings.noDocuments}>
          No documents available
        </Text>
      )}
    </SecureAreaWrapper>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use return when refreshing is true

```
const DocumentsListWidget = ({ refreshing }) => {

  const {
    documents: { documents },
    policy: {
      policyInfo: { PolicyId },
    },
  } = useSelector((state) => state);

  if(refreshing) return null

  return (
    <SecureAreaWrapper
      ...
    >
      {documents.length > 0 ? (
        <FlatList
          scrollEnabled={false}
          data={documents}
          ListHeaderComponent={Header}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Item
              ...
            />
          )}
        />
      ) : (
        <Text style={documentsListings.noDocuments}>
          No documents available
        </Text>
      )}
    </SecureAreaWrapper>
  );
};
```